# Remove repeat numbers so far removes next number Big O(n)

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

The problem says to remove repeat numbers. Then, keep the numbers in an array without the others repeated. For example, [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 , 2, 2] would be [0, 1, 2 ] The numbers should be UP To Time Complexity Big O(n) and space complexity O(1).

So far what I have is the next number checking the next. It does not get the number that is farther of it. For example: [ 0, 1, 2 ,3 , 4, 5, 6, 2, 8, 9 ]
The 2 is farther away but does not get checked by the code below. D[i+1]

I cannot use hash map or hash set.

```
    while (i < A.length) {
        i++;
        D = A;
        if (i < A.length - 1) {
            if (A[i] == D[i+1]){
                B[i] = D[i + 1];
            } else
                A[i] = A[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have to use the same array or can you copy the result to a new array?

Comment: I am not sure you can do it in O(n), everything I can think of is like O(n + 10) or worse.  The first solution that comes to mind would be to use a temp array of size 10.  Then iterate over the array in question and just increment the offset of the value `++`.  Then anything in the result array that is not zero is a desired value, in order.  The issue is that you need to iterate over the result array leading to n + 10. I am assuming "space complexity O(1)" means that it does not grow with the complexity of n, however it is larger than just n.

Comment: You can use a different array. This is possible. It is homework assignment.

Comment: If you use a hash table/set you could keep track of repeated numbers, and your ammortized complexity will be O(n). However, the space complexity of O(1) means that you cannot use any extra memory. Sorting the array will be O(n*log n), and will not produce "stable" output of [3 1 5], for example. Are you sure about the space complexity ?

Comment: I forgot to say I cannot use a hash table. I was explained that there are two pointers. The first checks the second. Then, the right moves if it is correct. The left stays. The right moves if it is wrong, too. Basically, the left only moves when there is a new repeated number.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `System.arraycopy` or `Arrays.copyOfRange`?

Comment: Michelle, what you mention as algorithm can work in O(n) only if the duplicates are clustered like 222, 111, 555., 222 would yield 2,1,5,2. It will be in O(n) and won't use any extra storage (even the result can be kept in place). However, your example explicitly excluded all duplications not only the clustered ones. Check your assignment carefully

Comment: @Michele two pointers will only work if your array is sorted

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "check the next", you must "check all preceeding".

The question then becomes, "how can I check if a number exists in any number of other elements in constant time"?

Use a `HashSet`. All operations of a hash-based structure are O(1).

Consider using the two methods `add()` and `contains()` of `HashSet`.

I leave the code writing to you...

Comment: I cannot use a hash map or hash set.

Comment: @Michele then you could write your own

Comment: And using an extra hash set/table will lead to space complexity of O(n) not constant.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do the task in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space, if input array is not sorted (and from your words - it is not).

It's not possible because in order the element to be removed you have to check, that there is a duplicate in any position before or any position after in array.

To check for duplicate you will either have to:

- scan the input array (this will lead to `O(n^2)` time of overall algorithm)
- use additional space, e.g. by using `Set` (this will lead to `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space).

So basically you have to trade-off time for space, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible until and unless the array is sorted one with linked list or marking elements as Integer.MIN_VALUE, "space and time trade off" applying this principal if we need faster time then we need to trade off space and vice versa .

- if using array then you can just mark the duplicate element as Integer.MIN_VALUE(in java or -2^16 in c/c++)
  and you can ignore this value.
- if linked list is used and array is sorted then just check next node
  with previous node and remove the next duplicate node.